# How to check if ajax cal was made and when it was completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a following code to hide the page loader image when the page is completely loaded (including any pending ajax call).

```
$('document').ajaxStop(function() {
    // place code to be executed on completion of last outstanding ajax call here
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
  });
```

It is working fine. However, some pages on the site do not have ajax calls and this code doesn't run there.
So I need a code to first check if there is any ajax call on the current page, if so, then check if it is completed and then run this code to hide the loading image.

Comment: did you try this ? $(window).load(function () { alert("page loaded"); });

Comment: yes i tried this before, doesn't wait for ajax calls to be completed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13785272)

Comment: Use debugger tools like fiddler.which keeps track of all requests and responses http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: @Aravind : keeping tracks is not the issue here

Comment: Use this tool and u will know if that page has Ajax Cal and the status code corresponding to that Ajax call will tell u if it is completed or not. By that u will know which page has Ajax call then use developer tools and F10 to parse through each line in the code and find where the call is made. Finally use this link http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/ to achieve your task.

Comment: Thanks Arvind. I know where are the Ajax calls on all pages, this is time consuming, so was wondering if there is any quick and generic code I could implement

Answer (score 1):

If you hide the loader by default, and then use `ajaxStart` to show it, and hide again on `ajaxStop`, it should do what you want *(I think)*

```
.se-pre-con { display : none; }
```

and

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".se-pre-con").show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use always method like this

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
// if success
.done(function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
// if failed
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
// or use always for completed request
.always(function() {
  alert( "complete" );
});
```

hope this help :)

Comment: Bu some pages have upto 5 separate ajax calls